# ggplot showing incorrect numbers

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this data:

```
 structure(list(Sexo = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Female", 
"Male"), class = "factor"), Status = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("Active", "Terminated"), class = "factor"), Freq = c(1367L, 
7030L, 394L, 940L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

When I try to plot it, it shows all wrong. what am I doing wrong, please?

```
razao1%>%
  ggplot(aes(x=as.factor(Status), fill = factor(Status)))+
  geom_bar(position = "fill")+ 
  facet_wrap(~Sexo)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it shows all wrong"? The plot looks like it would build fine.

Answer (score 1):

If by "it shows all wrong" you mean that you're only getting y-values of 1, then it's likely due to not having a y-value in the original `ggplot` call.

Try this:

```
razao1%>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Status, y = Freq, fill = Status))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+ 
  facet_wrap(~Sexo)
```

Which will generate this plot:
[image]